# Why is my View not displaying value of ViewBag?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a little blog application with posts and tags. This is my model for **Post**:

```
namespace HelloWorld.Models
{
    public class Post
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.DateTime)]
        public DateTime PostDate { get; set; }

        public List<Tag> Tags { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int PostId { get; set; }
    }

    public class CreatePostView
    {
        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Text)]
        public string Title { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
        public string Description { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Tags")]
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "Please select a tag")]
        public string SelectedTag { get; set; }
        public SelectList TagList { get; set; }

        [Required]
        public int PostId { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And model of **Tag** consist of **string TagName**, **int TagId**, **List Posts**.

When I create a new Post I use **CreatePostView** and my view is:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="create-post-form">

        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">

            <strong>Title</strong>

            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">

            <strong>Description</strong>

            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Description, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedTag, Model.TagList, "Add tag")
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.SelectedTag)

        <div class="post-create-button">
            <input type="submit" value="Create">
        </div>

        <div class="back-to-list-button">
            @Html.ActionLink("Back", "Index")
        </div>
    </div>
}
```

And now I want to display my tag that I selected. I put value of selected tag in ViewBag, but it does not display. Maybe it's silly, but I do not know how to fix it. My Create action of PostsController:

```
// POST: Posts/Create
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult Create(CreatePostView post)
        {
            Post currPost = new Post {
                                       Title = post.Title, 
                                       Description = post.Description, 
                                       PostDate = DateTime.Now, 
                                       Tags = null };

            ViewBag.Tag = post.SelectedTag.ToString();
            ViewBag.Trash = "texttexttexttexttext"; // It's strange, but it not displayed.

            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                //var tags = db.Tags.Where(s => s.TagName.Equals(post.SelectedTag)).ToList();     
                //currPost.Tags = tags;

                db.Posts.Add(currPost);
                db.SaveChanges();
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Posts");
            }

            return View(currPost);
        }
```

My view with all Posts (use model **Post**)

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        <article class="post">
            <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Title)</h3>
            <p>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Description)</p>

            <!--None of them is not shown-->
            <p><strong>Tag: @ViewBag.Tag</strong></p>
            <p><strong>Trash: @ViewBag.Trash</strong></p>
        </article>
    }
```

Comment: The answer here is to not use a Viewbag. Your model is strongly typed while a Viewbag is dynamic. Avoid them at all cost.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`ViewBag` is used when returning a view, not when redirecting to another action.  Basically it doesn't persist across separate requests.  Try using `TempData` instead:

```
TempData["Tag"] = post.SelectedTag.ToString();
```

and in the view:

```
<p><strong>Tag: @TempData["Tag"]</strong></p>
```

Comment: Thanks! But I get an error when I use `TempData.Tag`. Then I use `TempData["Tag"]`.

Comment: @Geronimo: It's possible it's a dictionary instead of a dynamic, this was all free-hand code :)  I'll update the answer, thanks!